# How to get profile url when using facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

i want to user profile url, which is redirect to user profile

api url:-
    https://graph.facebook.com/search/?q=shakira&fields=id,name,link,picture&type=user&access_token={xyz}

got result:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1087110374693765",
         "name": "Vanessa Montes",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1087110374693765/",
         "picture": {
            "data": {
               "is_silhouette": false,
               "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13516314_1081918975212905_1979454008154600349_n.jpg?oh=2bb569a97c1e9144333407640edd41eb&oe=57ED4B09"
            }
         }
      },
```

Comment: I think above information is what we call user profile, what you are expecting??

Comment: The `link` is the user profile URL.

Comment: i want to user profile link @mandeep singh

Comment: link is not a actual user profile link, this is a virtual link which redirect to user login @p4sh4

Answer (score 1):

For privacy reasons, you can´t get the direct link to a user profile anymore. You can only get a link that redirects to the real profile URL, but that is all you need anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help @luschn